# Issue upgrading Craft 2 to 3

Tags: error-message, craft3, error, upgrades

I'm attempting to upgrade my Craftsite from 2 to 3, which I have done so, however I seem to be getting a few deprecation errors.

**The first error is:**

> The auto-generated validation key stored at
>   /Users/User/My-Site/craft/storage/runtime/validation.key has been
>   deprecated. Copy its value to the “securityKey” config setting in
>   config/general.php.

To which I assumed I should just add 'securityKey' => 'xxxxxx', but the error hasn't gone.

**The second error is:**

> The environmentVariables config setting has been renamed to aliases.

Which to be honest im not sure how to fix.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those aren't so much errors as deprecation messages, meaning you should fix them sometime before Craft 4 comes out where they'll be going away and become real errors for you. :)

> To which I assumed I should just add 'securityKey' => 'xxxxxx', but the error hasn't gone.

They won't go away automatically.  Go to `yoursite.com/admin/utilities/deprecation-errors`, then you can click the "x" for the message on the far right to clear it.  It won't come back again if it has been fixed.

> The environmentVariables config setting has been renamed to aliases.

You'll want to convert your old environmentVariable to use the new aliases syntax.  You can see examples of that here:

https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/configuration.html#aliases